# How to text wrap some cells in a google sheet column?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, array-formulas

I have a google sheet, wherein the first two columns are filled using "Arrayformula" from a pivot table. Is it possible to merge some of the cells in first column while using Arrayformula.
Below is an image of sample data which I am obtaining from the pivot. I would like to have "Porsche" from 1st column to be text wrapped for all its  corresponding customer IDs.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdt4I.png

Thank you

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `query` to filter out rows where there are no Customer IDs.

#### Formula:

```
=arrayformula(query({A1:B}, "where Col2 is not null"))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

If this isn't the one you want, kindly provide your expected result as I'm unsure with how you used the term "text wrapped"